# Error when passing list of float values to function

Tags: python, floating-point

---

**Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'**

I am passing two lists to a functions to find the starting distance,ending distance ,starting time, ending time using sesnor data. when the list contains only integer values, it doesn't throw any error and works fine but when i tried to convert the list to floating value , its showing an error

```
x = ["%.2f"%(b*1000) for b in t] # t is a list of time values
y =  [c*0.002 for c in values]# values is a list of sensor values    
z = ["%.2f"%(d*48.484) for d in y]
p1,t1 = min_distance(z,x)
p2,t2 = max_distance(z,x)





def min_distance(self,z,x):

        count = True
        i =  0
        while count and (i+1) !=len(z):
            if abs(z[i] - z[i+1]) >= 1: 
            count = False
            else:
            i +=1
        min_value = z[i])
        min_time = x[i])
        return min_value,min_time


def max_distance(self,z,x):    

        count = 0
        j =  1
        while count<20:
            if abs(z[-j] - z[-j-1]) >=1: 
            count +=1
            else:
            j +=1
        max_value = z[-j+20]
        max_time = x[-j+20]
        return max_value,max_time
```

Comment: `x`, `y` and `z` are arrays of strings, not integers or floats. You are creating them using string substitution, which inserts and formats a float value but results in a string. What if you just use, for example: `x = [b*1000 for b in t]` and so on? Then format any resulting string only when you need output visible to the user.

Comment: Oh I thought it is a integer or float but not string.  Initialy i have used the same x = [b*1000 for b in t] and got everything right. But i now i need to calculate the values in two decimal points for further calculation. What else i can try to change this?

Comment: To ensure you get a float, ensure either that `b` and `c` are floats, or force the integer to a float by adding a decimal point. For example, if `b` is an integer, `b*1000` will result in an integer, but `b*1000.0` or `float(b*1000)` will give a float.

Comment: I have made my comments into an answer - I hope this is helpful.

Comment: yeah thanks a lot .. Now it is working. i have also changed this to          x = [round(float(b*1000),2)  for b in t] to display in two decimal places

Comment: No problem! If it has been helpful, consider marking the answer as accepted. Also let me know if I can help in any other way.

Comment: yeah sure...Thanks mate!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x`, `y` and `z` are arrays of strings, not integers or floats. You are creating them using string substitution, which inserts and formats a float value but results in a string.

To ensure you get a float, ensure either that `b` and `c` are floats, or force the integer to a float by adding a decimal point. For example, if `b` is an integer, `b*1000` will result in an integer, but `b*1000.0` or `float(b*1000)` will give a float

Try, for example: `x = [b*1000 for b in t]` and so on then format any resulting string (like you had done) only when you need output visible to the user.